# HTML code in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I am using AWS Lambda to send an email after the API gateway relays the information from the web page through the contact form. 
I want to also include inside the lambda code a piece of HTML code that will be actually the body of the email. I want it to look cool.
How can one make that happen?

1. I have tried to insert the HTML code where the text for the email is and it gives me a bunch of errors, maybe is not supposed to be inserted as is.

Here is the code

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
var ses = new AWS.SES()
var RECEIVER1 = 'admin email'
var RECEIVER11 = 'contact email'
var SENDER = 'sender email'

exports.handler = function (event, context) {console.log('Received event:', event) sendEmail(event, function (err, data) {context.done(err, null)})}

function sendEmail (event, done) {
var params = {

        Destination: {
        ToAddresses: [
            RECEIVER1
        ]
    },
    Message: {
        Body: {
            Text: {
                Data: 'Name: ' + event.name + '\nPhone: ' + event.phone + '\nEmail: ' + event.email + '\nDescription of email: ' + event.description,
                Charset: 'UTF-8'
            }
        },
        Subject: {
            Data: 'Variable: ' + event.name,
            Charset: 'UTF-8'
        }
    },
    Source: SENDER
}
ses.sendEmail(params, done)

var params1 = {

        Destination: {
        ToAddresses: [
            RECEIVER11
        ]
    },
    Message: {
        Body: {
            Text: {
                Data: ''

<html>              
...
</html>
   ,
                Charset: 'UTF-8'
            }
        },
        Subject: {
            Data: 'Variable: ' + event.name,
            Charset: 'UTF-8'
        }
    },
    Source: SENDER
}
ses.sendEmail(params1, done)
}'
```

Comment: Give us a snippet of your code/your lambda. Then we will suggest the best solution, then you will be happy.

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your code and how you're implementing this?

Comment: Also is it nodejs lambda, python lambda.. PLease clarify .

Comment: Also, what are the error codes/messages that you are receiving.

Comment: var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
var ses = new AWS.SES()
 
var RECEIVER1 = 'the admin person who will receive the contact form info'
var RECEIVER11 = 'the email of the one that is going to receive the THANK YOU FOR CONTACTING US HTML EMAIL'


var SENDER = 'sender address'
 
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    console.log('Received event:', event)
    sendEmail(event, function (err, data) {
        context.done(err, null)
    })
}

Comment: function sendEmail (event, done) {
    var params = {
        
            Destination: {
            ToAddresses: [
                RECEIVER1
            ]
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Text: {
                    Data: 'EMAIL TEXT',
                    Charset: 'UTF-8'
                }
            },
            Subject: {
                Data: 'Variable: ' + event.name,
                Charset: 'UTF-8'
            }
        },
        Source: SENDER
    }
    ses.sendEmail(params, done)
 }

Comment: I had to break the code in two pieces.. I had to compress it as well. Not all is showing, but is basically two sets of the same code. One sends an email with the contact form to the admin of the page and the other section sends an email to the person contacting with the THANK YOU

Comment: Also is Node.js 6.10

Comment: @Hercules_Daniel don't add code in comments, it's unreadable. Edit your original question to add that, and format it correctly so we can read it.

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to this forum, makes sense to go back and edit... sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this...

```
Message: {
    Body: {
        Text: {
```

...what you are looking for is this:

```
Message: {
    Body: {
        Html: {
```

Text means **only text** -- not HTML.

You can actually include both, with a plain text equivalent of your message inside the `Text` object, which is displayed by some mail viewers as a preview or when mousing-over a message, or if the viewer can't display HTML mail.  It may also be of benefit to people with accessibility issues, such as visual impairments.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#sendEmail-property

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out. I read the whole document of SES email and I never found that. That doc from AWS is different from where I was reading.

Comment: is it possible to include in the same code, how to send a text message... like the same way ses.sendemail is invoked, maybe there is such function to send text message?

Comment: @Hercules_Daniel sending text messages is done with Simple Notification Service (SNS), not Simple Email Service (SES).   You'd use [`publish()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#publish-property) with a `PhoneNumber` argument.